# How to filter a object list by an array of IDs?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a object list, and an array. My array has few IDs (strings) that customer selected. My object has an attribute ID. I would like to filter my list by an array of IDs. Is there a way I can filter it using predicate or lambda?

```
public class PaymentDueData {

    private long paymentScheduleId;
    private String invoiceNumber;

}

String []  selectedInvoices;
```

Comment: Do you want to only include payment data matching selected invoices, or exclude them?

Comment: include payment data matching selected invoices

Answer (score 1):

First, I would turn the array `selectedInvoices` into a `Set<String>` to enhance lookup:

```
HashSet<String> invoices = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(selectedInvoices));
```

Then, you need to check the presence of the element's id `data.getInvoiceNumber()` in the set:

```
(...)
    .stream()
    .filter(data -> invoices.contains(data.getInvoiceNumber()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: why converting to hashset? you can simple use it as stream.

Comment: right. But why don't simply use Arrays.binarySearch?

Comment: yeah! I was thinking on memory side.

Comment: With that solution you will end up always with a empty list. Note that `new ArrayList<PaymentDueData>().stream()` will retrieve always an empty stream.

Comment: You will instantiate a new List and also a HashSet... how is this memory optimized?

Comment: @Tet, I believe it is obvious that `new ArrayList<PaymentDueData>()` is gonna be replaced by the real source. OP didn't clarify what the source is/how it is obtained or initialised.

Comment: @GiovaniGrifante, the `Arrays.asList` is a shortcut to make a quick transformation and is regarded as a temporal structure. I don't think it can be THE problem here.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this most probably:

```
 paymentDueDataCollection.stream()
                         .filter(x -> Arrays.stream(selectedInvoices)
                               .anyMatch(y -> y.equals(x.getInvoiceNumber()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If the `paymentDueDataCollection` is large, the creation of a new stream every time and do the `.anyMatch()` could be problematic.